# You've earned the "Caucus" badge for an election. HUH?

Tags: discussion, badges

I'm always happy to earn a new badge, but I don't understand why this one was awarded to me 2 days ago.

The qualification for earning it is:

> Visited an election during any phase of an active election. This badge
>   can be awarded multiple times.

But the election it points to is the 2011 Election that ended Jun 15 '11 at 20:00. Plus, there does not appear to be any newer elections (nor did I actually visit any DYI election two days ago).  I *may* have visited the Election back in 2011, but I could not say one way or the other.

Thoughts?

Comment: Also see this blog post - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/06/election-participation-badges/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Caucus](https://diy.stackexchange.com/badges/90/caucus) (and [Constituent](https://diy.stackexchange.com/badges/91/constituent)) are new badges, designed to encourage participation in elections.

You visited the election page at some point in the past - most probably during our one and only (so far) election.

New badges, where possible, are awarded retrospectively so that existing users aren't disadvantaged if they've already been engaging in the behaviour the badge is designed to reward.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I am wondering... "Badges, where possible, are awarded retrospectively so that existing users aren't disadvantaged if they've already been engaging in the behaviour the badge is designed to reward." Do you have an example where someone would be _disadvantaged_ by getting an badge right away? Thanks!

Comment: @Jim - I think you misunderstood. Take this badge for example. If the badge only looked at behaviour from today then all the users, like you, who participated in the last election wouldn't be rewarded for doing so. In this case the badge can be awarded retrospectively as your visit and the fact you voted have been recorded.

Comment: Sorry to be so dull here, but are you saying that the Caucus badge is a _new_ badge and thus is being awarded retroactively? I certainly understand that I may not be awarded a badge immediately, but it may take a day or two, but a _year_? (Not that I am complaining about it--*really, i'm not*, I am just trying to understand why it is being awarded a year later). If you don't have an answer to that specific question, that fine.

Comment: @Jim - yes. The badge is *new*. I should have made that clear in the answer.

Comment: *AH*, now _that_ makes sense!

Comment: Jim, this is a new badge and it's awarded to you 1 year late because it didn't exist 1 year ago when you voted. From now on if you participate in an election again you will be awarded the badge immediately.

Comment: @md1337 - Thanks, I see that now. ChrisF didn't specify that in his original post, but has now gone back and added it. Makes perfect sense.